# How to compile .c file with OpenSSL includes?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, openssl

I am trying to compile a small .c file that has the following includes:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

In the same folder where I have the .c file I have a /openssl with all those files (and more), also in synaptic package manager I see OpenSSL installed, I am trying to compile with this:

```
gcc -o Opentest Opentest.c -lcrypto
```

but I always get the errors:

```
error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
error: openssl/x509.h: No such file or directory
error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
```

The file I want to compile is only a .c file, doesn't have Makefile or ./configure.

I already tried:

```
env CFLAGS=-I/path/to/openssl/
```

and tried to compile again but I get the same errors.

What should I do in order to compile with OpenSSL includes?

Comment: Also see [How to compile openssl with relative rpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9399677/608639) and [Build OpenSSL with RPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29858870/608639) It ensures you get the expected libraries at runtime.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Your include paths indicate that you should be compiling against the *system's* OpenSSL installation.  You shouldn't have the `.h` files in your package directory - it should be picking them up from `/usr/include/openssl`.

The plain OpenSSL package (`libssl`) doesn't include the `.h` files - you need to install the development package as well.  This is named `libssl-dev` on Debian, Ubuntu and similar distributions, and `openssl-devel` on CentOS, Fedora, Red Hat and similar.

Comment: @jahmax: No worries.  You will find that most library packages in Debian-based distros have a `*-dev` package that you will need to compile against the library (and often a `*-dbg` package containing debugging symbols for the library).

Comment: Right on. libssl-dev did the trick for building osslsigncode-1.5.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: How to install `libssl-dev` in wondows7?

Comment: @Wafeeq just copy your comment and paste it into a search engine.

Comment: Apparently params.h is missing in /usr/include/openssl/ after following these steps

Comment: From a lower voted answer below: On CentOS, do: `yum install openssl-devel`

Comment: On Fedora 36, this is `openssl-devel`.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `-I` flag to gcc properly.

`gcc -I/path/to/openssl/ -o Opentest -lcrypto Opentest.c`

The `-I` should point to the directory containing the `openssl` folder.

Comment: gcc -I/home/username/Programming/openssl/ -o Opentest -lcrypto Opentest.c it gives me the same errors :(

Comment: To elaborate on your answer if the openssl folder is `/path/to/openssl/` then the option needs to be `-I/path/to/` @jahmax. so you want `/home/username/Programming/`

Comment: @Earlz : Thanks, I tried to say that with the last explicit line but it must have gotten missed.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but now I get errors in the includes inside openssl/ssl.h, that include files that are inside /openssl/subfolders, how can I make gcc to find those?

Comment: @jah if you are being "bad" and your own project's include path(`openssl/*`) doesn't match OpenSSL's (possible `*`) then you could have this problem. The best solution is to change your project to use `ssl.h` instead of `openssl/ssl.h` etc. The quick fix is to set include paths for both `/path/to/` and `/path/to/openssl/`

Answer (score 11):

Use the snippet below as a solution for the cited challenge;

```
yum install openssl
yum install openssl-devel
```

Tested and proved effective on CentOS version 5.4 with keepalived version 1.2.7.

Answer (score 9):

You need to include the library path (-L/usr/local/lib/)

`gcc -o Opentest Opentest.c -L/usr/local/lib/ -lssl -lcrypto`

It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

If the OpenSSL headers are in the `openssl` sub-directory of the current directory, use:

```
gcc -I. -o Opentest Opentest.c -lcrypto
```

The pre-processor looks to create a name such as "`./openssl/ssl.h`" from the "`.`" in the `-I` option and the name specified in angle brackets.  If you had specified the names in double quotes (`#include "openssl/ssl.h"`), you might never have needed to ask the question; the compiler on Unix usually searches for headers enclosed in double quotes in the current directory automatically, but it does not do so for headers enclosed in angle brackets (`#include <openssl/ssl.h>`).  It is implementation defined behaviour.

You don't say where the OpenSSL libraries are - you might need to add an appropriate option and argument to specify that, such as '`-L /opt/openssl/lib`'.

Comment: i tried -L/usr/lib but I still get errors in all the includes from ssl.h, why gcc cant find them?

Answer (score 4):

From the openssl.pc file

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenSSL
Description: Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries and tools
Version: 0.9.8g
Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lssl -lcrypto
Libs.private: -ldl -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lz
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

You can note the Include directory path and the Libs path from this. Now your prefix for the include files  is `/home/username/Programming` . 
Hence your include file option should be `-I//home/username/Programming`.

(Yes i got it from the comments above)

This is just to remove logs regarding the headers. You may as well provide `-L<Lib path>` option for linking with the `-lcrypto` library.

Comment: I still get errors in all the includes used by ssl.h, why gcc cant find those?

Answer (score 1):

For this gcc error, you should reference to to the [gcc document about Search Path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).

In short:

1) If you use angle brackets(<>) with #include, gcc will search header file firstly from system path such as */usr/local/include* and */usr/include*, etc.

2) The path specified by -L*dir* command-line option, will be searched before the default directories.

3)If you use quotation("") with #include as #include "file", the directory containing the current file will be searched firstly.

so, the answer to your question is as following:

1) If you want to use header files in your source code folder, replace <> with "" in #include directive.

2) if you want to use -I command line option, add it to your compile command line.(if set CFLAGS in environment variables, It will not referenced automatically)

3) About package configuration(openssl.pc), I do not think it will be referenced without explicitly declared in build configuration.

Comment: `-ldir` is wrong. with `-l`, it is always `lib` instead of `dir`.

Comment: @GulluButt It should be -Ldir. I have revised my answer.

Comment: I am having similar problem which is mentioned in this question. I am trying to compile an example from link below but it is not working. I am not sure if my installation if ok or not. When I say `-lssl`, it looks for `ssl.dll` in installation directory of `openssl` ? 

http://simplestcodings.blogspot.de/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html#!/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html

Comment: @GulluButt, For Linux, -lssl option will make gcc search libssl.so or libssl.a  for symbols needed.

Comment: on windows not on Linux.