# How to build git on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, git, ssl, mingw

I am trying to build Git from this repository: [git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git), which is supposedly last version of git with windows-specific changes. I am working in MinGw32 environment on Windows.

I have run into the following problem: when I try to build git, I get:

```
compat/mingw.h:134:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: 
No such file or directory  #include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

Why is that? I have openssl built an installed from source in the same environment, using `make` -> `make install` sequence.
In particular, `ssl.h` was installed into `/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/ssl.h` and `/local/ssl/include/openssl/ssl.h`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) with MinGW-w64.

Open Mingw64 shell, add the following packages:

```
$ pacman -Sy mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl \
  mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre2 \
  mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
```

Clone and build Git (if you don't have Git yet, you can download a [.zip](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git) instead)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/git-for-windows/git.git
$ cd git
$ make
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (multiple errors even after adding these packages and others), but the other hand the Git for Windows project now delivers *its own* (MinGW-w64-based) *SDK installer*, which works perfectly, without affecting your existing msys2/mingw-w64 install.

Answer (score 3):

The current answer, as of the project website https://gitforwindows.org/#contribute, is to download the "Git for Windows SDK" from that page.

When you execute the installer it clones the SDK, and opens a "Git for Windows SDK" prompt - something very close to an MINGW64 prompt, as far as I can tell.

then:

```
sdk cd git
sdk build
```

And you're set, you have a locally-built git.exe! The SDK installs to `C:\git-sdk-64` by default, and the git project gets created in `C:\git-sdk-64\usr\src\git`.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2015, you can find a more complete example of Windows build through the new ci (continuous integration) folder and its [`ci/run-windows-build.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dcad9a4c87daa4c90d5504e87973d2d5a5d31ff4/ci/run-windows-build.sh) script (March 2017).

It is used in a [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1eb437020a2c098a7c12da4c05082fbea10d98c9/.travis.yml#L47-L56), meaning you can delegate the actual build to a remote build environment: [travis-ci.org/git/git/builds](https://travis-ci.org/git/git/builds).
That way, you don't have to worry about your own local workstation having or missing dependencies.

Comment: The shell script just does `curl https://git-for-windows-ci.azurewebsites.net/api/TestNow`

Comment: @rustyx Yes it does. With, as parameter passed to the  URL: `?action=trigger&branch=$BRANCH&commit=$COMMIT&skipTests=false`: that is what trigger the *build*. https://github.com/git/git/blob/dcad9a4c87daa4c90d5504e87973d2d5a5d31ff4/ci/run-windows-build.sh#L55

Comment: OP asks how to do that locally, not on azure CI.

Comment: @rustyx I agree. That is why I proposed this answer as an *alternative*, and concluded with "That way, you don't have to worry about your own local workstation having or missing dependencies.". Hopefully, that might inspire other readers to consider this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [openssl](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) first and then try to build it. Also follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368683/how-to-compile-c-file-with-openssl-includes) to get an understanding of your issue(though it is linux specified).

Comment: i have openssl installed.
It is located in /local/ssl.

Comment: Have you installed the development package (`libssl-dev`) for openssl ?

Comment: I have installed it from source

Comment: Try going through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368683/how-to-compile-c-file-with-openssl-includes. This might help

Comment: In the end i could build by invoking `make` with `NO_OPENSSL=1'. That was one of the methods in the comments you have proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it works best with Cygwin.  You need to install all the packages it needs or else it will fail the build.

Answer (score 0):

**prerequisites:**

MSYS2
add to PATH: `C:\msys64\usr\bin`

```
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb mingw-w64-x86_64-curl mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre2
```

add to PATH: `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

---

**build:** (ignore this if building for debugging)

`cmd.exe`

```
set MSYSTEM=MINGW64
make
```

---

`set MSYSTEM=MINGW64`
and packages
`mingw-w64-x86_64-curl` `mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre2` were what were missing for me

---

**build for debug:** https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Debugging-Git

create file `git/config.mak` (`git` is the repo cloned from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git.git)

```
DEVELOPER=1
ifndef NDEBUG
CFLAGS := $(filter-out -O2,$(CFLAGS))
ASLR_OPTION := -Wl,--dynamicbase
BASIC_LDFLAGS := $(filter-out $(ASLR_OPTION),$(BASIC_LDFLAGS))
endif
```

build

```
set MSYSTEM=MINGW64
make
```

---

**debug using vscode:**

```
{
  "name": "(gdb) C git",
  "type": "cppdbg",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\git.exe",
  "args": [
    "rev-parse",
    "HEAD",
  ],
  "stopAtEntry": true,
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "environment": [],
  "externalConsole": false,
  "MIMode": "gdb",
  "setupCommands": [
    {
      "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
      "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
      "ignoreFailures": true
    }
  ],
}
```